# How to make links in openlayers maked with target="_blank"

Tags: href, openlayers

Ho,
how can i add target="blank" to all links in elements of the openlayers 3.10.x component?
-- Rüdiger

Comment: Could you make an jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Here is a smal sample https://jsfiddle.net/4jxkpdkv/

Comment: The link creates the same code as my example but don't run?!

Comment: I cant get your jsfiddle run. maybe the problem is that you use '#' in your "href" to refer to the same page. I don't think you can combine it with target=blank

Comment: Ok, try http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/accessible.html and klick "Edit". Now set collapsible: true in line 10 in the script. In the left bottom corner a "i" button appears which opens an close the copyright box. As a example the links in the copyright should be modified to have target="_blank"

Comment: I tried to combine some google results and added `$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
  })
});` as the last part of my script section. It looks like it did the trick. But is this really correct?

Comment: Hopefully this fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/rgubler/fn7sq45t/

Comment: If i set `collapsible: false` the links are not modified because no button is clicked. How can I modify the links immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this jquery code:

```
$("#mapDiv").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    $("a").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    })
});
```

Which look like working as expected.

-- Tolotos